# Dynamically change SSRS variable into fact table ID

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have two tables... one that has the `Identifer` the end user will need to enter into the SSRS report variable however, this identifier cross references and ID that means nothing to the user and I will need to use that ID to query the information the user will need to see in the report.

tables are as follows... The `SampleID` is a concatenation of year, month, day and a sequential number... `Order_TestID` is just a sequential number

```
 Table: LIS_Results
 SampleID       |     Order_TestID
 1311120001            1234
```

The user will enter the `SampleID` into the variable of the SSRS report because it is a number commmonly used in the workflow... however the `Order_TestID` is what links the above table to this table below ultimately outputting the information the user will need to see.

```
 Table: LIS_Results_Log
 Order_TestID     |   Other columns I want to report
   1234                 various column I want to output in the SSRS report
```

So the user will enter 1311120001 into the SSRS report, how can I compare the `SampleID` to the `Order_TestID` table so that I can use that to query the `LIS_Results_Log` table, and would it be possible to convert it back?

I have tried a JOIN on these two tables so the user can use the sample ID but I get 744 records back when I should only recieve like 50 or 60 (sorry do not remember exact number). I have tried to just do a simple

```
SELECT * 
FROM LIS_Results lr, LIS_Results_Log lrl 
WHERE lr.Order_TestID = lrl.Order_TestID
```

but I get the same output of 744 rows.

I need to figure out how to convert the `SampleID` into the `Order_TestID` to query the `LIS_Results_Log` table, or possibly figure out how to report on both tables making sure that all unique rows with `Order_TestID` of 1234 output rather than 744 rows.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: gotcha... just listing everything I tried to get the outcome I needed... that was really the last thing I tried out of desperation... Any ideas or recommendations? or just pointing out bad habbits?  Thank you for edits on post btw, I am new to forum and still learning the features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly it should just be:

```
SELECT * --I don't recommend using a * by the way. Expand the column names if possible
FROM LIS_Results R
INNER JOIN LIS_Results_Log L ON L.Order_TestID = R.Order_TestID
WHERE R.SampleID = 1311120001
```

Comment: I had to test your query on a different server because original server is in use.
I am using 1311120154 in this example... the Order_TestID for that number is 4960424
when I run this query I get 20 rows
      SELECT * FROM LIS_Results r where r.SampleID = '1311120154'

When I run this query I also get 20 rows
      SELECT * FROM LIS_Results_Log l WHERE l.Order_TestID = '4960424'
when I try yours I get 400 rows. There should be 40.
      SELECT * FROM LIS_Results r INNER JOIN LIS_Results_Log l ON l.Order_TestID = r.Order_TestID WHERE r.SampleID = '1311120154'

Comment: If I understand my data in the tables I should only get 40 rows of data and do not understand why I am getting 400... and this did not solve my problem.

Comment: if you get 20 rows from LIS_Results for that SampleID and 20 from the other table then 20 * 20 = 400. You're getting a cartesian product. There must be another ID value or something that joins those tables together. Without knowing your schema I can't say what it is, but it has to be there.

Comment: Thank you David. That did solve my problem. Sorry for delayed reponse. I am new to SQL and now understand what a cartesian product is. Sorry for making this more complicated than it was, and thankyou for taking the time to help me out. It is Greatly Appreciated!